# Converting A timestamp string to the right format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a datafield, in the format : '13:55:07 03-01-2023'
This is 3rd of january and not 1st of March

I want to convert this into a timestamp, when I do it directly using
`pd.to_datetime(order_data['exch_tm'])`
I get the output of the timestamp like this : **Timestamp('2023-03-01 13:55:07')**

However, this is incorrect as it converting into 1st of march, whereas it should convert it into 3rd of January.

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(order_data['exch_tm'], dayfirst=True)` or provide a `format`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the datetime format always the same in the data? If so, what about using a format parameter to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime('13:55:07 03-01-2023', format='%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y')
Timestamp('2023-01-03 13:55:07')
```

Comment: Oh, I tried almost exactly this. Thanks it solves it!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to mention the format of date entered.

For eg:

> pd.to_datetime(order_data['exch_tm'],format='%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y'))

modify it as per your needs and you can find more about `datetime` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).